# Set notification for someday on a loop

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show local notification like what ever I set it on here like this picture:

[image]

When I click "Create story" button, I will send the story' properties to the notification.

My story has some properties like this:

```
@NSManaged var remindeAtHour: Int
@NSManaged var remindeAtMinute: Int
@NSManaged var remindeAtDaysOfWeek: [Bool] // -> This means that from
// Monday to Sunday, if it true, it is set, if it false, it not be set.
```

Here is my code of RemindNotification class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RemindNotification {

  var timerNotification = NSTimer()

  func notification(story: Story) {
    let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(story.remindeAtHour * 3600 + story.remindeAtMinute * 60)
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "Title"
    notification.alertBody = "It's time to take a photo"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeInterval)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    timerNotification.invalidate()
  }
}
```

I've already show local notification with this code.

[image]

But I want to set the day on it, so It can looply show notification on time of the days I set. For example, I set time with 8:30, and I choose some day "Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday", it's now 12:35 Tuesday, so at 8:30 on Wednesday, It will show notification, so on... And next week on Monday it will show again and again. How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can set maximum 64 local notifications at the time as mentioned in apple documentation.

> **Apple Doc says :** Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

**Solution**

Set notifications for next 5-6 days when app is opened by user if there is no scheduled notifications. Find scheduled notification using following method which returns list of all scheduled notifications, based on it schedule your next notifications.

```
NSArray *arrScheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
```

perform this on app launch.

Read more about [Local Notifications here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html)

**Alternate**

Schedule a calendar event. It allows you to set number of events at any point of time. Though its not associate with application, but it will show you reminder. You can choose it if it satisfies your requirement.

More details on [Calendar event is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1)